# How to make relation with multiple classes in Python ? or how to create class object in another class?

Tags: python, class

I have created a model in python for backend work

**Here is my python code**

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, _id=None):
        self._id = _id
        if self._id is not None:
            self.contact = Contact()
            self.contact.user_id = self._id


class Contact:

    def __init__(self, _id=None):
        self._id = _id
        self.user_id = None
        if self._id is not None:
            self.vehicle = Vehicle()
            self.vehicle.contact_id = self._id


class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, _id=None):
        self._id = _id
        self.contact_id = None
        self.user_id = None

    def create_company(self, company_name):
        # check if user id is set
        if None in (self.contact_id, self.user_id):
            return {'result': False, 'msg': 'user or contact id is not set'}
        # here i will use user id and contact id
        return {'result': True, 'msg' : 'ok'}
```

I want to create vehicle company which is linked to userid and contact id

**i want to do like this**

```
User('user_id').Contact('contact_id').vehicle.create_company('any name')
```

But i am getting error which i know why but dont know how to achive soluction

**Error i am getting**

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'Contact'
```

Comment: You can't use another class like a method like that.

Comment: Did you mean `User('user_id').contact.vehicle...`?

Comment: yes if that will work ,but that way i cant define contact id.

Comment: Then you either have to pass a `Contact` instance, or the contact id to `User`.

Comment: i thinking to create another funtion in user class to get contact class object with contact id. but dont know if this is proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i managed to achieve by this code, Please suggest for more better way to do this.

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, _id=None):
        self._id = _id

    def Contact(self, _id):
        if self._id is None:
            raise Exception({'result':False, 'msg': 'user id is not set'})
        self.contact = Contact(_id)
        self.contact.user_id = self._id


class Contact:

    def __init__(self, _id=None):
        self._id = _id


    def Vehicle(self):
        if self._id is None:
            raise Exception({'result': False, 'msg': 'contact id is not set'})
        self.vehicle = Vehicle()
        self.vehicle.contact_id = self._id
        if hasattr(self, 'user_id'):
            self.vehicle.user_id = self.user_id



class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, _id=None):
        self._id = _id

    def create_company(self, company_name=None):
        # check if user id is set
        if not hasattr(self, 'user_id') or not hasattr(self, 'contact_id'):
            return {'result': False}
        # here i will use user id and contact id
        return {'result': True, 'msg' : 'ok'}
```

and use it like this

```
test = User('admin')
test.Contact('person')
test.contact.Vehicle()
print(test.contact.vehicle.create_company())
```

and result is what i want

```
{'result': True, 'msg': 'ok'}
```